# Enabling/Disabling Options using JQuery when using bootstrap-select

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, html-select, bootstrap-select

When *input -> option d* is empty *option -> d* should be disabled. (It does)

As soon as *input -> option d* has some value *option -> d* should be enabled. (It **does't**)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (!$('#option_d').val()) {
    $("#right_option option[value='D']").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //.removeAttr('disabled')
  }
  if (!$('#option_e').val()) {
    $("#right_option option[value='E']").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //.removeAttr('disabled')
  }

});

$("#option_d, #option_e").on("change keyup paste", function() {
  if (!$('#option_d').val()) {
    $("#right_option option[value='D']").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //.removeAttr('disabled')
  } else {
    $("#right_option option[value='D']").removeAttr('disabled');
  }
  if (!$('#option_e').val()) {
    $("#right_option option[value='E']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
    $("#right_option option[value='E']").removeAttr('disabled');
  }

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.10/css/bootstrap-select.css">


<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label class="control-label">Option (A)</label></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="option_a" placeholder="Option (A)" required /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label class="control-label">Option (B)</label></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="option_b" placeholder="Option (B)" required /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label class="control-label">Option (C)</label></td>
    <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="option_c" placeholder="Option (C)" required /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label class="control-label">Option (D)</label></td>
    <td><input id="option_d" class="form-control" type="text" name="option_d" placeholder="Option (D)" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label class="control-label">Option (E)</label></td>
    <td><input id="option_e" class="form-control" type="text" name="option_e" placeholder="Option (E)" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label class="control-label">Right Answer</label></td>
    <td>
      <select id="right_option" class="form-control selectpicker" name="part" data-live-search="true" required>
        <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select Quiz</option>
        <option value="A" data-tokens="Option A">Option A</option>
        <option value="B" data-tokens="Option B">Option B</option>
        <option value="C" data-tokens="Option C">Option C</option>
        <option value="D" data-tokens="Option D">Option D</option>
        <option value="E" data-tokens="Option E">Option E</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.10/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

When *input -> option d* is empty *option -> d* should be disabled. (It does)

As soon as *input -> option d* has some value *option -> d* should be enabled. (It **does't**)

> ***It works fine when I don't use any bootstrap. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ld7jf56p/1/)***

Comment: `$("#right_option option[value='D']").attr('disabled', $.trim($('#option_d').val()) == "")`

Comment: Your fiddle should have "bottom of head" instead of "onload"

Comment: Also `on("change keyup paste")` can be written `on("input")`

Comment: `Your fiddle should have "bottom of head" instead of "onload"` I didn't get it

Comment: **[updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ld7jf56p/3/)**

Comment: You fiddle has `$(document).ready(function() {` and se setting for the fiddle is 'on load' (click the JavaScript dropdown and change "load type")

Comment: With `bottom of head` not giving results. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ld7jf56p/4/)

Comment: That is another issue - but leaving it to "on load" will interfere with document.ready

Comment: Still it doesn't solves the issue

Comment: Now the bootstrap runs, but you do NOT have to use if `$("#right_option option[value='D']").attr('disabled', $.trim($('#option_d').val()) == "");` is the complete statement

Comment: No, same issue https://jsfiddle.net/Ld7jf56p/5/

Comment: Went through it but none of them are suitable for my question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use ***bootstrap-select*** your code changes from:

```
<td>
      <select id="right_option" class="form-control selectpicker" name="part" data-live-search="true" required>
        <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select Quiz</option>
        <option value="A" data-tokens="Option A">Option A</option>
        <option value="B" data-tokens="Option B">Option B</option>
        <option value="C" data-tokens="Option C">Option C</option>
        <option value="D" data-tokens="Option D">Option D</option>
        <option value="E" data-tokens="Option E">Option E</option>
      </select>
    </td>
```

#### to:

```
<td>
  <div class="dropdown bootstrap-select form-control show">
    <select id="right_option" class="form-control selectpicker" name="part" data-live-search="true" required="" tabindex="-98">
        <option value="" selected="" disabled="" hidden="">Select Quiz</option>
        <option value="A" data-tokens="Option A">Option A</option>
        <option value="B" data-tokens="Option B">Option B</option>
        <option value="C" data-tokens="Option C">Option C</option>
        <option value="D" data-tokens="Option D" disabled="disabled">Option D</option>
        <option value="E" data-tokens="Option E" disabled="disabled">Option E</option>
      </select>
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-light bs-placeholder" data-toggle="dropdown" role="combobox" aria-owns="bs-select-1" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-expanded="true" data-id="right_option" title="Select Quiz">
      <div class="filter-option"><div class="filter-option-inner"><div class="filter-option-inner-inner">Select Quiz</div></div> </div></button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu show" x-placement="bottom-start" style="max-height: 554px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 162px; position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 38px, 0px);">
      <div class="bs-searchbox"><input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" role="combobox" aria-label="Search" aria-controls="bs-select-1" aria-autocomplete="list"></div>
      <div class="inner show" role="listbox" id="bs-select-1" tabindex="-1" style="max-height: 490px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 98px;">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu inner show" role="presentation" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
          <li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-1-0" tabindex="0"><span class="text">Option A</span></a></li>
          <li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-1-1" tabindex="0"><span class="text">Option B</span></a></li>
          <li><a role="option" class="dropdown-item" id="bs-select-1-2" tabindex="0"><span class="text">Option C</span></a></li>
          <li class="disabled"><a role="option" class="dropdown-item disabled" id="bs-select-1-3" aria-disabled="true" tabindex="-1"><span class="text">Option D</span></a></li>
          <li class="disabled"><a role="option" class="dropdown-item disabled" id="bs-select-1-4" aria-disabled="true" tabindex="-1"><span class="text">Option E</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Which means the user sees *unordered list* instead of *select option*, so we also have to change the class and attributes in *unordered list*.

Now, if you are typing something in *Option D* value, you have to remove all your `disabled` class, `aria-disable` attribute and change `tabindex` value to *0* in:

```
<li class="disabled"><a role="option" class="dropdown-item disabled" id="bs-select-1-3" aria-disabled="true" tabindex="-1"><span class="text">Option D</span></a></li>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (!$('#option_d').val()) {
    $("#right_option option[value='D']").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //.removeAttr('disabled')
  }
  if (!$('#option_e').val()) {
    $("#right_option option[value='E']").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //.removeAttr('disabled')
  }


  $("#option_d, #option_e").on("change keyup paste", function() {
    if (!$('#option_d').val()) {

      $("#right_option option[value='D']").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //.removeAttr('disabled')
    } else {
      $("#right_option option[value='D']").removeAttr('disabled');
      $("#bs-select-1-3").removeAttr('aria-disabled');
      $("#bs-select-1-3").removeClass('disabled');
      $("#bs-select-1-3").attr('tabindex', '0');
      $("#bs-select-1-3").parent().removeClass('disabled');
    }
    if (!$('#option_e').val()) {
      $("#right_option option[value='E']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $("#right_option option[value='E']").removeAttr('disabled');
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.10/css/bootstrap-select.css">


<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label class="control-label">Option (D)</label></td>
    <td><input id="option_d" class="form-control" type="text" name="option_d" placeholder="Option (D)" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label class="control-label">Option (E)</label></td>
    <td><input id="option_e" class="form-control" type="text" name="option_e" placeholder="Option (E)" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label class="control-label">Right Answer</label></td>
    <td>
      <select id="right_option" class="form-control selectpicker" name="part" data-live-search="true" required>
        <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select Quiz</option>
        <option value="A" data-tokens="Option A">Option A</option>
        <option value="B" data-tokens="Option B">Option B</option>
        <option value="C" data-tokens="Option C">Option C</option>
        <option value="D" data-tokens="Option D">Option D</option>
        <option value="E" data-tokens="Option E">Option E</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.10/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

In the above snippet it changes as we are expecting, ***but*** comes to its first stage again when we click the button to select the option. For that, we will also do the same thing when the button is clicked.

```
$("[aria-owns='bs-select-1']").click(function(){
        if (!$('#option_d').val()) {

    $("#right_option option[value='D']").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //.removeAttr('disabled')
  } else {
  $("#right_option option[value='D']").removeAttr('disabled');
    $("#bs-select-1-3").removeAttr('aria-disabled');
    $("#bs-select-1-3").removeClass('disabled');
    $("#bs-select-1-3").attr('tabindex','0');
    $("#bs-select-1-3").parent().removeClass('disabled');
  }
  if (!$('#option_e').val()) {
    $("#right_option option[value='E']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
    $("#right_option option[value='E']").removeAttr('disabled');
  }
    });
```

---

### Final Working Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (!$('#option_d').val()) {
    $("#right_option option[value='D']").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //.removeAttr('disabled')
  }
  if (!$('#option_e').val()) {
    $("#right_option option[value='E']").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //.removeAttr('disabled')
  }


  $("#option_d, #option_e").on("change keyup paste", function() {

    if (!$('#option_d').val()) {

      $("#right_option option[value='D']").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //.removeAttr('disabled')
    } else {
      $("#right_option option[value='D']").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    if (!$('#option_e').val()) {
      $("#right_option option[value='E']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $("#right_option option[value='E']").removeAttr('disabled');
    }

  });

  $("[aria-owns='bs-select-1']").click(function() {
    if (!$('#option_d').val()) {

      $("#right_option option[value='D']").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //.removeAttr('disabled')
    } else {
      $("#right_option option[value='D']").removeAttr('disabled');
      $("#bs-select-1-3").removeAttr('aria-disabled');
      $("#bs-select-1-3").removeClass('disabled');
      $("#bs-select-1-3").attr('tabindex', '0');
      $("#bs-select-1-3").parent().removeClass('disabled');
    }
    if (!$('#option_e').val()) {
      $("#right_option option[value='E']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $("#right_option option[value='E']").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.10/css/bootstrap-select.css">


<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label class="control-label">Option (D)</label></td>
    <td><input id="option_d" class="form-control" type="text" name="option_d" placeholder="Option (D)" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label class="control-label">Option (E)</label></td>
    <td><input id="option_e" class="form-control" type="text" name="option_e" placeholder="Option (E)" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label class="control-label">Right Answer</label></td>
    <td>
      <select id="right_option" class="form-control selectpicker" name="part" data-live-search="true" required>
        <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select Quiz</option>
        <option value="A" data-tokens="Option A">Option A</option>
        <option value="B" data-tokens="Option B">Option B</option>
        <option value="C" data-tokens="Option C">Option C</option>
        <option value="D" data-tokens="Option D">Option D</option>
        <option value="E" data-tokens="Option E">Option E</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.10/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```